# Access a variable defined in a js , from an html page?

Tags: javascript, html, variables

I have set a variable in one of my javascript files and i want to access that variable in an html file . How do i do the same?

here us my javascript code(file name is JSUI.js):

```
      JSUI = function () {
            this.glistName = null;
            this.renderUI = function(list) {
                this.glistName = list.listName;
                window.location="page2.html";   
            };
        };
var gJSUI = new JSUI();
```

page2.html:

```
 <body>
    <script src="js/JSUI.js"></script>
    ListName: <input type="text" id="listName"></input> 
    </body>


    <script type="text/javascript">

         if(document.readyState="complete"){
             document.getElementById("listName").value = gJSUI.glistName;
         }

    </script>
```

Basically page2.html  gets loaded when renderUI method of JSUI.js is called and i want to populate a textbox present in page2.html with a variable defined in JSUI.js file .How do I achieve the same?

Comment: Where is `glistName` *declared*? (E.g., where is `var glistName` or `let glistName`, if anywhere?)

Answer (score 1):

you have actually created a class but there are some mistakes and the most important : you don't initialize the class itself.

Try this:

```
JSUI = function () {
    this.glistName = null;
    this.renderUI = function(list) {
        this.glistName = list.listName;
        window.location="page2.html";   
    };
};
```

And in you page:

```
if(document.readyState="complete") {
    var myobject = new JSUI();
    document.getElementById("listName").value = myobject.glistName;
}
```

Comment: Suggest also having them fix their [implicit global](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html) (`JSUI`).

Comment: Still not working myobject.gListName is null . 
Is this happening because the renderUI method of JSUI is called from another page (page1.html).

So the flow goes like this
page1.html ---> JSUI.renderUI()-->page2.html.

Comment: @user2713255: `glistName` will be `null` until you call `renderUI` on `myobject`, passing in an object with a `listName` value that's not `null`.

Comment: also going to another page will indeed clear your variable. You'll need cookies or sessions to store variables across different pages, or use a querystring!

Comment: Edited the code as per your suggestion. Oh, if going to another page clears the variable yes then definitely this would not work. Yes will have to come up with another approach.

Comment: btw isnt is weird that even though the object of `JSUI`  created has global scope ,still I am losing the member variable `glistName` when another page is loaded?I am setting `glistName`  using the same global object @Verthosa

Comment: javascript is stateless and clientside. This said, navigating to another page reloads the initial javascript so as long as you don't explicitely pass the variable value (through url or cookies or whatever), your variable will hold the initial value

Answer (score 1):

There are different methods to achieve the desired result:

1) Set the variable to the global Window object;
2) Use a modular pattern where you export the variable in one js file, and import it in the other (which I'd use). Use AMD (requirejs), commonjs, ES6 modules, ... ;
3) Use the localstorage to store state;
4) Use the DOM to store state;
5) Keep state at the server and use dehydrate to extract state into JS objects to different components when the js gets loaded;
6) Use ajax to get state from the server when the page is loaded and dispatch the state to different components that need it on app bootstrap;

Comment: Nice answer. Global window object seems to be the most efficient.